# Combinatorial nature of basis of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, systems-of-equations

Consider an homogenous linear system of equations:

$$Ax=0$$

The vector space of solutions coincides with the null  space of A. I'm particularly interested in the case when $A$ is rank deficient, i e the solution can be parameterized.

What is the combinatorial nature of the set of basis ?

Which are the algorithmic procedures available to generate "different" basis of the null space ?

Comment: Use Gauss-Jordan elimination on the augmented matrix A|0 and take the nonzero columns.

Comment: @MoseWintner That generates one basis. The OP is asking for a process to produce other possible bases.